# How can I center a placeholder text in an Entry with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, placeholder, tkinter-entry

Here is the code:

```py
from tkinter import *

class EntPlaceHold(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder="placeholder", color='#610B21'):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.placeholder_color = color
        self.default_fg_color = self['fg']

        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.foc_in)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.foc_out)

        self.put_placeholder()
    def put_placeholder(self):
        self.insert(0, self.placeholder)
        self['fg'] = self.placeholder_color
    def foc_in(self, *args):
        if self['fg'] == self.placeholder_color:
            self.delete('0', 'end')
            self['fg'] = self.default_fg_color
    def foc_out(self, *args):
        if not self.get():
            self.put_placeholder()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `justify` option to center the placeholder:

```py
def put_placeholder(self):
    self.insert(0, self.placeholder)
    self['fg'] = self.placeholder_color
    self['justify'] = 'center'  # center the placeholder

def foc_in(self, *args):
    if self['fg'] == self.placeholder_color:
        self.delete('0', 'end')
        self['fg'] = self.default_fg_color
        self['justify'] = 'left'  # left justify for normal input
```